# How I can limit the result in class-search.php?

Tags: php

This is the code search.php -  this code combine search data from database and pagination not working.

```
<?php include_once('include/header.php'); ?>
<?php
//Declaration
$search_term = '';
$search_results = false;

require 'include/db.php';

//Check if search data was submitted
if (isset($_GET['pages'])) {
// Include the search class
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/class-search.php' );

// Instantiate a new instance of the search class
$search = new search();

// Store search term into a variable
$search_term = $_GET['pages'];

// Send the search term to our search class and store the result
$search_results = $search->search($search_term);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Search</h1>
    <div class="search-form">
        <form action="" method="get">
            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="search-field">Search</label>
                <input type="search" name="pages" placeholder="Enter your search term..." results="5"  autocomplete="off">
                <input type="submit" value="Search">
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php
        $perpage = 2;
        if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        } else {
            $page = 1;
        }
        $start = ($page - 1) * $perpage;
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    if ($search_results) :
        ?>
        <div class="results-count">
            <p>
                <?php
                echo $search_results['count'];
                ?> results found
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="results-table">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Number</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Race</th>
                        <th>IC Number</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Contact Number (Home)</th>
                        <th>Handphone Number</th>
                        <th>Email</th>

                        <th>Action</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php
                $no = 1;
                foreach ($search_results['results'] as $search_result) :
                    ?>
                    <div class="result">

                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $no ?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $search_result->cust_gender; ?> </td>
                            <td> <?php echo $search_result->cust_race; ?> </td>
                            <td> <?php echo $search_result->cust_ic; ?>
                            <td> <?php echo $search_result->cust_name; ?>

                            <td> <?php echo $search_result->cust_add1; ?>
                                <?php echo $search_result->cust_add2; ?>
                                <?php echo $search_result->cust_add3; ?>
                                <?php echo $search_result->cust_postcode; ?>
                                <?php echo $search_result->cust_town; ?>
                                <?php echo $search_result->cust_state; ?> </td>
                            <td><?php echo $search_result->cust_home_con; ?></td>

                            <td> <?php echo $search_result->cust_hp_contact1; ?>
                                <?php echo $search_result->cust_hp_contact2; ?> </td>
                            <td>  <?php echo $search_result->cust_email; ?> </td>


                    </div>
                    <?php
                    $no++;
                endforeach;
                ?>

            </table>
        </div>


        <!-- 
                                                    <div class="search-raw">
                                                        <pre>
        <?php
        print_r($search_results);
        ?>
                                                        </pre>
                                                    </div>
        -->

        <?php
    endif;
    ?>


    <?php
    $sql2 = "select * from customer_info ";
    $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    $total_record = mysqli_num_rows($query2);
    $total_page = ceil($total_record / $perpage);
    ?>
    <nav>
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li>
                <a href="search.php?pages=1" aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_page; $i++) { ?>
                <li><a href="search.php?pages=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <li>
                <a href="search.php?pages=<?php echo $total_page; ?>" aria-label="Next">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code class-search.php

```
    $start = null;
    $perpage = null;
    class search {

      private $mysqli;


      public function __construct() {
        // Connect to our database and store in $mysqli property
        $this->connect();
      }

      private function connect() {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', 'root', 'fimos' );
      }


      public function search($search_term) {
        // Sanitize the search term to prevent injection attacks
        $sanitized = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($search_term);


        // Run the query
        $query = $this->mysqli->query("
          SELECT *
          FROM customer_info
          WHERE cust_name LIKE '%{$sanitized}%'
          OR cust_ic LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' {$start} , {$perpage} 
        ");

        // Check results
        if ( ! $query->num_rows ) {
          return false;
        }

        // Loop and fetch objects
        while( $row = $query->fetch_object() ) {
          $rows[] = $row;

        }

        // Build our return result
        $search_results = array(
          'count' => $query->num_rows,
          'results' => $rows,
        );

        return $search_results;
      }
    }
```

Why I still cannot display 2 data / page? I click in pagination function 1, 2 , 3 also same record, that change for me search page 1 also the result got 1 only. I have using class for search function. hope can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php include_once('include/header.php'); ?>
<?php
//Declaration
$search_term = '';
$search_results = false;

require 'include/db.php';

//Check if search data was submitted
if (isset($_GET['pages'])) {
// Include the search class
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/class-search.php' );

// Instantiate a new instance of the search class
$search = new search();

// Store search term into a variable
$search_term = $_GET['pages'];

// Send the search term to our search class and store the result
$search_results = $search->search($search_term);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Search</h1>
    <div class="search-form">
        <form action="" method="get">
            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="search-field">Search</label>
                <input type="search" name="pages" placeholder="Enter your search term..." results="5"  autocomplete="off">
                <input type="submit" value="Search">
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php
        $perpage = 2;
        if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        } else {
            $page = 1;
        }
        $start = ($page - 1) * $perpage;
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    if ($search_results) :
        ?>
        <div class="results-count">
            <p>
                <?php
                echo $search_results['count'];
                ?> results found
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="results-table">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Number</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Race</th>
                        <th>IC Number</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Contact Number (Home)</th>
                        <th>Handphone Number</th>
                        <th>Email</th>

                        <th>Action</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php
                $no = 1;
                foreach ($search_results['results'] as $search_result) :
                    ?>
                    <div class="result">

                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $no ?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $search_result->cust_gender; ?> </td>
                            <td> <?php echo $search_result->cust_race; ?> </td>
                            <td> <?php echo $search_result->cust_ic; ?>
                            <td> <?php echo $search_result->cust_name; ?>

                            <td> <?php echo $search_result->cust_add1; ?>
                                <?php echo $search_result->cust_add2; ?>
                                <?php echo $search_result->cust_add3; ?>
                                <?php echo $search_result->cust_postcode; ?>
                                <?php echo $search_result->cust_town; ?>
                                <?php echo $search_result->cust_state; ?> </td>
                            <td><?php echo $search_result->cust_home_con; ?></td>

                            <td> <?php echo $search_result->cust_hp_contact1; ?>
                                <?php echo $search_result->cust_hp_contact2; ?> </td>
                            <td>  <?php echo $search_result->cust_email; ?> </td>


                    </div>
                    <?php
                    $no++;
                endforeach;
                ?>

            </table>
        </div>


        <!-- 
                                                    <div class="search-raw">
                                                        <pre>
        <?php
        print_r($search_results);
        ?>
                                                        </pre>
                                                    </div>
        -->

        <?php
    endif;
    ?>


    <?php
    $sql2 = "select * from customer_info ";
    $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    $total_record = mysqli_num_rows($query2);
    $total_page = ceil($total_record / $perpage);
    ?>
    <nav>
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li>
                <a href="search.php?page=1" aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_page; $i++) { ?>
                <li><a href="search.php?page=<?php echo $i; ?>&pages=<?php echo $_GET['pages']?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <li>
                <a href="search.php?pages=<?php echo $total_page; ?>&pages=<?php echo $_GET['pages']?>" aria-label="Next">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this before but nothing work. I update the <b>class-search.php<b>